# how can we create .svc file for WCF RIA services Class library

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-ria-services

I am developing a Silverlight application with WCF RIA Serivces. now I want to deploy the WCF service on different server and expose services as .svc files. I have used WCF class Library but not able to find how can we deploy Services on the seperate server.

Thanks,

Sharad Rastogi

Answer (score 1):

Can you deploy services like in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2010/03/29/silverlight-4-ria-services-ready-for-business-exposing-wcf-wsdl-services.aspx?PageIndex=2#comments?